# justify my being, as afraid as I was

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> 'There is simply nothing in my current reality to justify my being as afraid as I was.

Does it mean that he is the most afraid to justify himself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much context to work with but, simply put, it means that his fear cannot be justified (or "validated") by anything in his current life. So he has *no proper reason* to be as afraid as he was in that moment and his fear is strange because of it. It has no "source". "Justify" means "to prove or show to be *reasonable*" (taken from Merriam-Webster)

What's interesting is that the writer talks about his "current reality" when weighing a past emotion. So there is nothing in him *now* ("**is** nothing...current reality...") that can explain why his fear was unnatural in the past ("...as I **was**...")

Comment: The comma that you have put in the question title makes nonsense of the phrase. It's _justify my being... afraid_ with the addition of _as... as I was_ indicating that he was more afraid than he had reason to be.